# Why does this code snippet output undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 3;
(function(){
   console.log(x); 
   var x = 2;
})();
```

I am wondering why console.log prints out undefined for x?

Comment: Read about "hoisting".

Comment: Thanks for the direction,  I didn't know that hoisting only applied to declarations.